# Is is possible to scale pagekite on multiple machine?

Tags: pagekite

Is it possible to scale pagekite on multiple servers so that:

1. It is not anymore a single point of failure
2. When the traffic gets heavy it gets distributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public service on pagekite.net is distributed over about 50 relays all over the world, for those reasons. But also to reduce latency, you get better service if your relay is nearby.

So yes, but it's a fair bit of work.

If you need that sort of thing, maybe consider working with us?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have Pagekite for more than 500 units that is why I'm looking into a self hosted solution.